# GroupBy and SelectMany analogues in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

In C# I can group collection items, run subquery for each group and then return rows.

```
var rows = collection.GroupBy( item => item.Property).SelectMany( g => ...);
```

In `SelectMany` part query can run against the collection (due to the closure) or/and the grouped items. The results of subqueries are then combined.

My problem is that I do not know how to achieve the same with SQL query.

Subquery placed inside select can be parametrized but allows to return one row at most, and joins do not exclude items that do not belong to the group.

I have no sql-oriented mindset and apologize if it is really a dumb question.

Example of temporal DB:

```
id   instance_id    data    from        to

1    1              A       20140301    20140310
2    1              AA      20140311    20140321
3    2              B       20140301    20140305
4    2              BC      20140306    20140316
```

I need to run subqueries for each instance_id i.e. against historical data of the entity and select only part of the history for each entity.

Comment: If you use EF6, then you can turn on logging, then you can see the query that will be executed aginst the SQL-Server
conn.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine

Comment: You should show your schema (table(s), columns, data-types, PK's/FK's) and some sample data. Then you should tell us what you are trying to achieve and the desired result.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I added the example.

Comment: I think you are looking for [CROSS APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: @TomT write it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using CROSS APPLY like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT * 
  FROM othertable
  WHERE instance_id = mytable.instance_id)
```

I would recommend using a join if possible, but APPLY comes in handy if you don't have a simple join condition. [This article](http://explainextended.com/2009/07/16/inner-join-vs-cross-apply/) explains it nicely.